# MAAS and Juju Post-Bootstrap Connection Error

Tags: server, juju, maas

I am working with a rather weird issue using MAAS and Juju where after the bootstrap, machine "0" has been successfully created, I cannot deploy any services issuing a simple `juju deploy mysql`. To give a brief environment overview, I am running MAAS on Ubuntu Server 13.04 with the IP 10.0.0.10 and `juju` and `juju-core` are running on the same server. This is all run in a localized test lab too. Issuing a `juju status` reveals the following:

```
root@maas:~# juju status
2013-04-30 10:24:32,876 INFO Connecting to environment...
2013-04-30 10:24:33,439 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: not-started
    dns-name: test4.master
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-ee044686-b100-11e2-9927-52540089abb8/
    instance-state: unknown
  5:
    instance-id: pending
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-19
    relations: {}
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 5
        public-address: null
2013-04-30 10:24:33,496 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

The instance remains in a `pending` state indefinitely and a look at the debug log reveals that a connection is not being made to provision the instance:

```
2013-04-30 10:27:26,562: juju.agents.provision@ERROR: Cannot get machine list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/agents/provision.py", line 175, in process_machines
    provider_machines = yield self.provider.get_machines()
ProviderInteractionError: Unexpected ConnectionRefusedError interacting with provider: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

Now since this error is being generated on machine "0" every minute or so, I looked at a tcpdump to try and find out what was happening. After some digging, I came across this at the exact time the error was being logged:

```
10:27:26.561631 IP 127.0.0.1.33607 > 127.0.0.1.80: Flags [S], seq 1222093882, win 32792, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 454628 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
10:27:26.561651 IP 127.0.0.1.80 > 127.0.0.1.33607: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1222093883, win 0, length 0
```

Since machine "0" was deployed with MAAS via Juju, I don't think it would be running MAAS as well. To troubleshoot the issue, I created a SSH tunnel on machine "0" listening on port 80 (localhost) to the MAAS server port 80, e.g. 80:MAAS-Server-IP:80. After that, `juju status` changed to show the new machine out of the pending state:

```
  5:
    agent-state: not-started
    dns-name: test5.master
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-fe882bb2-b100-11e2-ba1c-52540089abb8/
    instance-state: unknown
```

All this to say, can someone please help me understand why the deployed machine "0" is attempting a connection to localhost port 80 rather than the MAAS server? Is this due to the fact I am running Juju and MAAS on the same server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an environment is bootstrapped, you must pay attention to the hostname in the environments.yaml, as it appears that is what is pushed out to subsequent machines. In my case, I had the server set to `http://localhost:80/MAAS`, thus causing machine "0", and any other machines for that matter, to attempt to make a connection to localhost and not the IP/hostname of the MAAS server. After destroying my environment, and bootstrapping it again with the server `http://10.0.0.10:80/MAAS`, everything seemed to deploy correctly. This is entirely an oversight on my part.