# Juju + openstack. Bootstrap is successful, But cant create any other services

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

A bit of context.

I'm running Openstack, deployed via MAAS running in VMWare 5.1u1.

I used this guide for MAAS: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/quantal/install.html

And this one for Openstack: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure (the section for MAAS and juju)

After some initial headaches, MAAS and Openstack seem to be happy(ish).

I've now set environments.yaml to attach to the openstack setup, which also seems to work. since `juju bootstrap` completes successfully and I see the instance spin up in openstack.

`juju status` looks good too:

```
$ juju status
2013-06-22 18:11:35,330 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:11:35,331 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:11:35,331 INFO Connecting to environment...
2013-06-22 18:11:35,401 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:11:36,041 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: 192.168.1.2
    instance-id: 460b0613-92a0-4dfd-8ad8-1b187d77a9fa
    instance-state: running
services: {}
2013-06-22 18:11:36,115 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

If I try to deploy any service, for example `juju deploy juju-gui`

```
$ juju deploy juju-gui
2013-06-22 18:15:32,060 INFO Searching for charm cs:precise/juju-gui in charm store
2013-06-22 18:15:33,320 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:33,320 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:33,402 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:33,428 INFO Connecting to environment...
2013-06-22 18:15:34,063 INFO Connected to environment.
2013-06-22 18:15:34,064 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,064 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,071 INFO Using cached charm version of juju-gui
2013-06-22 18:15:34,094 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,094 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,160 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,183 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,184 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,249 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,284 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,285 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,349 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,373 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,373 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,437 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,467 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,467 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,530 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,553 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,554 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,620 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:15:34,645 INFO Charm deployed as service: 'juju-gui'
2013-06-22 18:15:34,646 INFO 'deploy' command finished successfully
```

The command complete successfully, but nothing spins up in openstack.

I get some warnings about secure connections, yes, but I'd like to think that inst causing my problems

```
$ juju status
2013-06-22 18:20:35,763 WARNING OpenStack identity service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:20:35,763 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:20:35,764 INFO Connecting to environment...
2013-06-22 18:20:35,833 WARNING OpenStack compute service not using secure transport
2013-06-22 18:20:36,464 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: 192.168.1.2
    instance-id: 460b0613-92a0-4dfd-8ad8-1b187d77a9fa
    instance-state: running
  3:
    instance-id: pending
services:
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:precise/juju-gui-61
    relations: {}
    units:
      juju-gui/1:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 3
        public-address: null
2013-06-22 18:20:36,553 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

I've only been experimenting with juju for a week now, so I'm sot sure how to begin troubleshooting this. I'm sure it's something simple, there are just a thousand simple things to check. Any help would be appreciated.

environments.yaml

```
default: openstack_s3
environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://192.168.1.100:80/MAAS'
    maas-oauth: 'wXcWaJZWF3JUBk8m9d:PYD5g4uT5ve2QmDHn9:pv2fnEpUUPpU96TStYb59jqjeGqmrUdm'
    admin-secret: '|omitted|'
    default-series: precise

  openstack_s3:
    type: openstack_s3
    control-bucket: juju-openstack-admin-a1dd-ddf7023d869c
    admin-secret: bec797e973914c05b954db4ef0074235
    default-series: precise
    default-image-id: 25eaf6ca-8568-403f-b395-29b64dcf8566
    auth-url: http://192.168.1.112:5000/v2.0/
    username: admin
    password: openstack
    project-name: admin
    secret-key: 033f36a1e2524afea1142e6b2055c76b
    ec2-uri: http://192.168.1.108:8773/services/Cloud
    s3-uri: http://192.168.1.108:3333
```

```
$ juju --version
juju 0.7
```

Also, per [MAAS and Juju Post-Bootstrap Connection Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288559/maas-and-juju-post-bootstrap-connection-error) I've changed the hostnames in my environments.yaml to IPs. No change.

Answer (score 2):

After playing around with some of the "Type" variables in the environments.yaml file It Appears that I have gotten it to work with the ec2 type:

```
juju: environments
environments:
  openstack:
    type: ec2
    control-bucket: juju-openstack-admin-9d2d-bd3540c21308
    admin-secret: 8ad4d69fadc5455ebac26fc23b596563
    access-key: f4d6f64c0d3f4d72bf6c3fb8f03cf438
    secret-key: 033f36a1e2524afea1142e6b2055c76b
    ec2-uri: http://arqcp.master:8773/services/Cloud
    s3-uri: http://arqcp.master:3333
    default-series: precise
    default-image-id: ami-00000005
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like there are no machines available (in 'Ready' state) for MAAS to use to deploy the services. Could you please make sure that you have available machines to do so? If not, please do:

```
juju get-constraints
```

And show us the output. Maybe constraints are impeding MAAS from providing a node to juju.